# Node.js: Fail to deploy node.js application to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, node-modules

I'm trying to deploy my node.js app to heroku. I did everything as necessary, but i am getting error like this.

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  16.3.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 16.3.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.3.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 7.15.1
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! code E404
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/har-validator/-/har-validator-5.1.2.tgz - Not found
remote:        npm ERR! 404
remote:        npm ERR! 404  'har-validator@https://registry.npmjs.org/har-validator/-/har-validator-5.1.2.tgz' is not in the npm registry.
remote:        npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
remote:        npm ERR! 404
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
remote:        npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.7maaf/_logs/2021-06-13T18_35_23_460Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 944efd5ebf13ff49831d29f02a9a1f6565355373
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 944efd5ebf13ff49831d29f02a9a1f6565355373
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to stark-lowlands-47617.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/stark-lowlands-47617.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/stark-lowlands-47617.git'
```

I tried to do this:

```
git push heroku master:main
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "languagelearningapp",
  "engines" : { "node" : "16.3.0" },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "basic-auth": "^2.0.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "callback": "0.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fcm-node": "^1.3.0",
    "fcm-notification": "^2.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5",
    "sendotp": "^1.2.9"
  }
}
```

But it did not help. I also tried adding node modules to .gitignore, but it didn't work.
In particular, I tried switching to a different branch, which did not work well.

PLease help me.

Comment: Look at the error. It says that `npm ERR! 404  'har-validator@https://registry.npmjs.org/har-validator/-/har-validator-5.1.2.tgz' is not in the npm registry`. If you look up `har-validator` on npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/har-validator), you can see that the package is deprecated

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/895), it was a GitHub issue raised which also had a problem with `har-validator` being deprecated. One solution proposed stated that you would start by _upgrading the HLS plugin to remove the dependency on request which brings in har-validator_, but mind the fact that they used `ArtilleryIO`.

Comment: what's the version of node you are using on your local dev machine ?

Comment: @ WaLid LamRaoui, 16.3.0

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you need to **DOWNGRADE** `node` to the **LTS** version on your local machine (**use nvm for that**), then basically reconfigure your project to use the **LTS version** : delete `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, delete `node_modules` folder then run `npm init` and install the dependencies you're using like `bcrypt` etc ..

After that you need to edit your new `package.json` and tell heroku to use LTS version also by adding this :

```
"engines": {
    "node": "14.x" 
  },
```

your package.json should look something like this :

```
{
  "name": "languagelearningapp",
  "engines" : { "node" : "14.x" },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    // your project dependencies 
  }
}
```

i know i will come back for this later but this is what i would try first if i get the same issue.